# I failed Javascript tech interview but I dont know why

Tags: javascript

I was only allowed to use google document for writing.

Could you please tell me what I did wrong? The recruiter wont get back to me when I asked her why I failed

Task 1:
Implement function verify(text) which verifies whether parentheses within text are correctly nested. You need to consider three kinds: (), [], <> and only these kinds.

My Answer:

```
   const verify = (text) => {
   const parenthesesStack = []; 
   
  for( let i = 0; i<text.length; i++ ) {
const closingParentheses = parenthesesStack[parenthesesStack.length - 1]
if(text[i] === “(”  || text[i] === “[” || text[i] === “<”  ) {
    parenthesisStack.push(text[i]);
} else if ((closingParentheses === “(” && text[i] === “)”) || (closingParentheses === “[” && text[i] === “]”) || (closingParentheses === “<” && text[i] === “>”) ) {
   parenthesisStack.pop();  
} 
  };

return parenthesesStack.length ? 0 : 1;     
}
```

Task 2:
Simplify the implementation below as much as you can.
Even better if you can also improve performance as part of the simplification!
FYI: This code is over 35 lines and over 300 tokens, but it can be written in
5 lines and in less than 60 tokens.
Function on the next page.

// ‘a’ and ‘b’ are single character strings

```
function func2(s, a, b) {
    var match_empty=/^$/ ;
    if (s.match(match_empty)) {
        return -1;
    } 
    var i=s.length-1;
    var aIndex=-1;
    var bIndex=-1;
    while ((aIndex==-1) && (bIndex==-1) && (i>=0)) {
        if (s.substring(i, i+1) == a)
            aIndex=i;
        if (s.substring(i, i+1) == b)
            bIndex=i;
        i--;
    }
    if (aIndex != -1) {
        if (bIndex == -1)
            return aIndex;
        return Math.max(aIndex, bIndex);
    } else {
        if (bIndex != -1)
            return bIndex; 
        return -1;
    }
};
```

My Answer:

```
const funcSimplified = (s,a,b) => {
    if(s.match(/^$/)) {
        return -1;    
    } else {
        return Math.max(s.indexOf(a),s.indexOf(b))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell without the recruiter feedback. But i can tell that you missundertood the second function.

```
func2("mystrs", 's', 'm')          // returns 5
funcSimplified("mystrs", 's', 'm') // returns 3
```

You are returning `Math.max(s.indexOf(a),s.indexOf(b))` instead of `Math.max(s.lastIndexOf(a), s.lastIndexOf(b))`

The original code start at `i=len(str) - 1` and decrease up to `0`. They are reading the string backward.

A possible implementation could have been

```
const lastOccurenceOf = (s,a,b) => {
    // Check for falsyness (undefined, null, or empty string)
    if (!s) return -1;
    // ensure -1 value if search term is empty
    const lastIndexOfA = a ? s.lastIndexOf(a) : -1
    const lastIndexOfB = b ? s.lastIndexOf(b) : -1
    return Math.max(lastIndexOfA, lastIndexOfB)
}
```

or a more concise example, which is arguably worse (because less readable)

```
const lastOccurenceOf = (s,a,b) => {
    const safeStr = s || '';
    return Math.max(safeStr.lastIndexOf(a || undefined), safeStr.lastIndexOf(b || undefined))
}
```

I'm using `a || undefined` to force a to be undefined if it is an empty string, because:

- `"canal".lastIndexOf("") = 5`
- `"canal".lastIndexOf(undefined) = -1`
  original function would have returned `-1` if case of an empty a or b

Also, have you ask if you were allowed to use ES6+ syntax ? You've been given a vanilla JS and you implemented the equivalent using ES6+. Some recruiters have vicious POV.

Comment: ES syntax *is* vanilla JS.

Comment: @AdamPearson Thanks for pointing out, i've corrected my answer

Answer (score 1):

For starters, I'd be clear about exactly what the recruiter asked. Bold and bullet point it and be explicit.

Secondly, I would have failed you from your first 'for' statement.
See my notes:

```js
// Bonus - add jsdoc description, example, expected variables for added intention.

 const verify = (text) => {
// verify what? be specific. 

   const parenthesesStack = []; 
   
  for( let i = 0; i<text.length; i++ ) {  
// this could have been a map method or reduce method depending on what you were getting out of it. Rarely is a for loop like this used now unless you need to break out of it for performance reasons. 

const closingParentheses = parenthesesStack[parenthesesStack.length - 1]
// parenthesesStack.length - 1 === -1. 
// parenthesesStack[-1] = undefined

if(text[i] === “(”  || text[i] === “[” || text[i] === “<”  ) {
    parenthesisStack.push(text[i]);

// “ will break. Use "
// would have been more performant and maintainable to create a variable like this:
// const textOutput = text[i]
// if (textOutput === "("  || textOutput === "["  || textOutput === "<") {
 parenthesisStack.push(textOutput)

} else if ((closingParentheses === “(” && text[i] === “)”) || (closingParentheses === “[” && text[i] === “]”) || (closingParentheses === “<” && text[i] === “>”) ) {
   parenthesisStack.pop();  
// There is nothing in parenthesisStack to pop
} 
  };

return parenthesesStack.length ? 0 : 1;   
// Will always be 0.  
}
```

Not exactly what the intention of your function or logic is doing, but It would fail based on what I can see.
Test it in a browser or use typescript playground. You can write javascript in there too.